# Find Replace Short Part of URL using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Assume I have the following URL stored in variable called `content`:

```
http://www.example.com/watch?v=4444444&feature=related
```

---

**Problem:**

1. I need to replace watch?v= with embed/
2. I need to erase whatever comes after &

---

The final output would look like:

```
http://www.example.com/embed/4444444
```

I tried these two steps but didn't work:

```
content = content.replace('/watch?v=/', 'embed/');
content = content.replace('&*/g','');
```

The URL in page source code appears as:

```
http://www.example.com/watch?v=4444444&feature=related
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many errors:

- You are using a regular expression when you only need a string.
- You are writing your regular expressions as strings.
- To write 'match any characters' you need to write `'.*'`, not just `'*'`. The star *modifies* the previous token.
- There is no need to use the `g` flag here.

Try this instead:

```
 content = content.replace('watch?v=', 'embed/').replace(/&.*/, '');
```